# Expected 1 non-named argument, got 0 error while inserting data using CumulusCI

Tags: salesforcedx, cumulusci

I am trying to insert data in the ORG,

I am creating Dectionary of **kwargs

```
${Dist}=    Create Dictionary    Project__c=${Project_Id}    Description__c=Test    Data_Type__c=Percent    Type_of_Results__c=Input    Reporting_Frequency__c=Monthly    
${Indicatory_Id}=    Salesforce Insert   Indicator__c = ${Dist}
```

I am getting below error,

```
Keyword 'cumulusci.robotframework.Salesforce.Salesforce Insert' expected 1 non-named argument, got 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Salesforce Insert` Robot keyword takes the name of the sObject as its first parameter. There's an example in [`create_contact.robot`](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/blob/master/cumulusci/robotframework/tests/salesforce/create_contact.robot):

```
    ${contact_id} =       Salesforce Insert  Contact
    ...                     FirstName=${first_name}
    ...                     LastName=${last_name}
```

To make this work with a dictionary, you'd instead do

```
${cont} =        Create Dictionary  FirstName=${first_name}  LastName=${last_name}
${contact_id} =       Salesforce Insert  Contact  &{cont}
```

Note the `&` to unpack the dictionary into individual keyword arguments, and the first argument being the name of the sObject.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with   '&{cont}'

Answer (score 0):

From Stack Overflow, [Run Process throws error “expected at least 1 non-keyword argument, got 0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904146/run-process-throws-error-expected-at-least-1-non-keyword-argument-got-0/44677600#44677600):

> This problem can occur when `arg1` or `arg2` contain symbols that
>   Robot Framework itself recognises. Make sure you escape those with a
>   backslash.
>
> For example, see the following command:
>
> ```
> curl <args> "<url>/download?job=<name>"
> ```
>
> This will result in "Keyword 'Process.Run Process' expected at least 1
>   non-keyword argument, got 0." The issue is, that Robot Framework
>   thinks the `=` is an assignment, so you need to escape it:
>
> ```
> curl <args> "<url>/download?job\=<name>"
> ```
>
> Note the `job\=<name>` instead of `job=name`. There is no need to add
>   multiple spaces between a command and its arguments.